# How visualize j48 tree in weka

Tags: machine-learning, tree, classification, weka, j48

I have an output tree in weka but can't view it (right click ...). Is there a tool to generate the resulting tree in an understandable way from the copy of the log (figures)?

[image: tree results log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above textual representation cannot be converted into other formats, unless you write your own parser.

However, if you use the `-g` option on the command-line, the tree will get output on stdout in [dot-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)). You can then take this output and convert it into other formats, like PNG or PDF using the [GraphViz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The command "-g" on which prompt do you mean?
I am using the weka explorer tool, to make a prediction using multiple instance learning specifically the TLC algorithm.

Comment: You can use the SimpleCLI if you're not.comfortablr with using the terminal/command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Weka from the command line if you have java installed.
On my Windows machine from the Weka-3-9-5 directory:

C:\Weka-3-9-5> java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -C 0.25 -M 2 -t .\data\iris.arff

This gives you the output that you current have with the trees.  However:

C:\Weka-3-9-5> java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -C 0.25 -M 2 -t .\data\iris.arff -g

gives you a different format:

digraph J48Tree {
N0 [label="petalwidth" ]
...
}
and you can feed this to GraphViz to get a nice printed tree.
I put the digraph output into a tree.txt file and then generated a png image file through GraphViz:

C:\GraphViz> dot -Tpng tree.txt > tree.png